# how to pass variable/matrix/list/... from one r session to another, QUICKLY?

Tags: r, session

is there any quick way  ( like ctrl_c , cctrl_v quick ) to pass a variable/matrix/list/... from one session to another in R?

I am a beginner. what is the most commonly used method you apply for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could save it into a .rdata file and then load it

In session 1

```
save(mydata, file="mydata.rdata")
```

In session 2

```
load("mydata.rdata")
```

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that this will work as long as as the 2 sessions have the same ```wd```